# Android set animation on application start

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to provide an animation when my application starts. I have just one `ImageView` on my first activity and I want to load my activity with an animation (maybe there can be some animations playing with the imageview too) and after a few seconds to start the second activity with another animation. I'm not really familiar with animation and how can I create custom ones, that's why I need a little help/suggestions/advice which animations will look nice.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Do you have problem to start your app with an animation or do you want help on how to create animations? Please try to rephrase your question to make it easier understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

Initialization:

```
ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_animation);
AnimationDrawable loading_animation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();
```

Show:

```
loading_animation.setVisible(true, true);
loading_animation.start();
```

Hide:

```
loading_animation.setVisible(false, false);
loading_animation.stop();
```

Background of ImageView:
drawable.xml (in drawables folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_0" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_2" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_3" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_4" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_5" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_6" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_7" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_8" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

Hope this helps!

Have in mind that the animation WILL NOT start if the windows has not the focus!!

Comment: I didn't have much time to try it, but I have two questions : what is : `loading_places_animation` and why you are setting 9 images..I mean what they are doing actually?

Comment: The loading_places_animation is mispelling. I will update it. The drawable is a set of images that create an animation. Think of it for example, loading_0 has one 'X', loading_1 has two 'X', etc. Thus showing one after another creates an animation. Of course this is not the only way.

Comment: Oh, I got your idea! I will try that!